# Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java, android

I have two java classes Configuration.java and login.java

*Configuration.java*

```
public class Configuration {
    public Configuration() {}

    public String getparams() throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:/.../Desktop/configuration.txt");
        try {
            properties.load(fileStream);
            String ip = (String) properties.get("IP");
            String port = (String) properties.get("Port");
            return ip + port;

        } finally {
            try {
                fileStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

*login.java*

...

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
String ip=cfg.getparams();// error
String port=cfg.getparams();//error
private final String LOGIN_URL = "http://"+ ip +":"+port+"/webservice/login.php";
```

> can anyone help me please to resolve the error

Comment: where do you get the message?

Comment: I get the error when I call getparams() in Login.java

Comment: Can you show the code of `login.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Configuration cfg;
    String ip;
    String port;
    private String LOGIN_URL;
    //other variables

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //here you initialize your variables
        try {
            cfg = new Configuration();
            String[] params = cfg.getparams();
            ip = params[0];
            port = params[1];
            LOGIN_URL = "http://"+ ip +":"+port+"/webservice/login.php";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle the exception
        }
        //.. your other code ...
    }
    //... your other methods ...

   }
```

Also change your Configuration file like this:

```
public class Configuration {
    public Configuration() {}

    public String[] getparams() throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:/.../Desktop/configuration.txt");
        try {
            properties.load(fileStream);
            String ip = (String) properties.get("IP");
            String port = (String) properties.get("Port");
            return new String[]{ip, port};

        } finally {
            try {
                fileStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To Kushtrim P:  do I have to put your suggestion in a method ?

Comment: The method getparams() throws an IOException , so wherever you call it, you should surround it with a try-catch statement. So just add the try-catch to your code in login.java

Comment: Because I know that try catch bloc must be in a methde because when i did it without  methode an error Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

Comment: Well yeah, you should initialize your variables on you onCreate(...) method

Comment: Thank you for your reply 
just a note :

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Just I'm getting this error because I'm using LOGIN_URL in my other code
can you help me please

Comment: LOGIN_URL cannot be resolved to a variable in the rest of code !

Comment: Thank  you a lot Kushtrim P for your patience  and great help.
Well, I'm working on an android application( xampp and php scripts for webservice) for login and registration but the problem is when I run my application, the registration is ok but the login dosen't work :/ any idea ?

Comment: That's unrelated to your current question, so you should post another question about that problem, complete with you code and your error log

Comment: Ok Kushtrim P 
Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the signature of getParam to not throw an error. I see you are doing it partially for call to properties.load();

Something like:

public class Configuration {

```
public Configuration() {}

public String getparams() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fileStream = null;
    try {

        fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:/.../Desktop/configuration.txt");

        properties.load(fileStream);
        String ip = (String) properties.get("IP");
        String port = (String) properties.get("Port");
        return ip + port;

    } 
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
   finally {
        try {
            fileStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

}

You might want to move new Properties into the try block if it can also throw.

Comment: LOGIN_URL cannot be resolved to a variable in my rest of code !

Comment: You mean the url which getParam returns?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `throws IOException` from **Configuration.java** and handle the exception with try-catch block. `throws` only declares exception that it may occur, it does not handle the exception.

```
public class Configuration {
    public Configuration() {}

    public String getparams() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:/.../Desktop/configuration.txt");
        try {
            properties.load(fileStream);
            String ip = (String) properties.get("IP");
            String port = (String) properties.get("Port");
            return ip + port;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                fileStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```