# Java making FileReader a member variable

Tags: java, filereader

So I use the line a lot.

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file)
```

and I want to make this line a member variable. Like this:

```
private FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
```

The problem is that java doesn't like this and gives the error:

```
The default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor Java(16777362)
```

So I made a constructor like this:

```
protected Json() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //
}
```

the problem is, is that I use the JSON class in different classes and those classes will give the same error, so I had to edit the other classes, but that ended up looking really ugly and gave a lot of problems. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you consider to handle (try/catch) the exception sooner? Or is that not feasible?

Comment: Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354791/java-error-default-constructor-cannot-handle-exception-type-filenotfound-except), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854207/default-constructor-cannot-handle-exception-type-ioexception-thrown-by-implicit) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772709/while-constructing-the-default-constructor-can-not-handle-exception-type-excep), all of which discuss the same problem

Comment: use an aggregation instead on a composition  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468285/8030651 ➡️ you can localize problem with `FileReader ` initialization

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to do it like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(file));
```